# Read session id from a cookie file saved by CURL

Tags: shell, curl, cookies

I have saved a cookie file to the disk using CURL command. Now I want to read the session ID from the cookie file and I wanna send it to another CURL request. How do I go about it?

The cookie file looks like this.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_localhost FALSE   /HazelcastSessClus/ FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  C08191738299B771AB28EB49A18124EC
```

Comment: Can you show sample of saved cookie file and your expected output?

Comment: Post it by editing your question otherwise it is difficult to read from comments.

Answer (score 4):

Session ID is the last string in the Cookie file. 
What I did for the time being:

```
SESSION_ID=$(cat cookies.txt | tr -d '\n' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
SESSION_ID=$(echo "$SESSION_ID" | awk '{ print $(NF) }')
```

This is not a right approach, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v f='JSESSIONID' '$0 ~ f {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($(i-1)==f) {print $i; exit}}' file
C08191738299B771AB28EB49A18124EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the contents of the cookie file, here's a general approach:

```
awk '/regex identifying the line you want/ { print $field_you_want }' cookie.txt
```

for example:

```
awk '/^CookieId:/ { print $2 }' cookie.txt
```

(That said, as someone who has done shell development practically full time, for this kind of task it would very likely be better (for you and whoever has to maintain the software) to use a different language like Python, Ruby or Java. They have much more sophisticated and programmer friendly string handling. For example, [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) is mandatory and simple, splitting and joining strings doesn't look like line noise, the equivalent of `set -o errexit` is always enabled, and they have actual exception handling.)

Answer (score 0):

This works too

```
SESSION_ID=$(tail -1 cookies.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $NF}')
```